When building Angular project I get this error No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=108 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.19.1
I tried to set up angular project. I followed this instructions but I get this error every time.
C:\C#\frontend\my-app>npm start

> my-app@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

Application bundle generation failed. [0.441 seconds]

✘ [ERROR] No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=108 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.19.1
    attempted loading from: C:\ and package: @/-win32-x64
 [plugin angular-compiler]


✘ [ERROR] No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=108 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.19.1
    attempted loading from: C:\ and package: @/-win32-x64
 [plugin angular-compiler]


Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...

this is my ng version:

Angular CLI: 18.0.5
Node: 18.19.1
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 18.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1800.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   18.0.5
@angular-devkit/core            18.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      18.0.5
@angular/cli                    18.0.5
@angular/ssr                    18.0.5
@schematics/angular             18.0.5
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.7


Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?
I have deleted (manually too) and reinstalled node, tried to use different node versions.

can you try to remove node_modules and run npm i again

Tried this multiple times, I even reinstalling whole node and npm

is it possible to share a link to the project?

https://github.com/amakamoonbug/Angular

Problem soved, I used incorrect directory naming so compiler couldnt find angular.
